# jqgrid set cell editable false dynamically on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a `jqgrid` populated by some fields. I want some of the cells to be

```
editable:true
```

or

```
editable:false
```

based on a condition

Here's my function (EDITED):

```
var grid = $("#mygrid");
var getColumnIndexByName = function(gr,columnName) {
var cm = gr.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
for (var i=0,l=cm.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
        return i; // return the index
    }
}
return -1;
};
function abilitaDisabilitaEditRecord() {
var pos=getColumnIndexByName(grid,'descrizione');
var pos2=getColumnIndexByName(grid,'endDate');
var allIds = $('#mygrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
var cells = $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child("+(pos+1)+")",grid[0]);
var cells2 = $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child("+(pos2+1)+")",grid[0]);
for (var i = 0; i < allIds.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<cells.length; j++) {
        var cell = $(cells[j]);
        var cell2 = $(cells2[j]);
    var checkDataFine = $('#mygrid').jqGrid('getCell', allIds[i], 'date');
    if (!checkDataFine==false) {
        cell.addClass('not-editable-cell');
        cell2.addClass('not-editable-cell');
        }   
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working solution:

```
var grid = $("#mygrid");
var getColumnIndexByName = function(gr,columnName) {
var cm = gr.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
for (var i=0,l=cm.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
        return i;
    }
}
return -1;
};


function changeEditableByContain() {
var pos=getColumnIndexByName(grid,'field1');
var pos2=getColumnIndexByName(grid,'field2');
var pos3=getColumnIndexByName(grid,'field3');
var pos4=getColumnIndexByName(grid,'field4');
var allIds = $('#mygrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
var cells = $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child("+(pos+1)+")",grid[0]);
var cells2 = $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child("+(pos2+1)+")",grid[0]);
var cells3 = $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child("+(pos3+1)+")",grid[0]);
var cells4 = $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child("+(pos4+1)+")",grid[0]);
for (var i = 0; i < allIds.length; i++) {
        var cell = $(cells[i]);
        var cell2 = $(cells2[i]);
        var cell3 = $(cells3[i]);
        var cell4 = $(cells4[i]);

    if (condition...) {
        cell.addClass('editable-cell');
        cell2.addClass('editable-cell');
        cell3.addClass('editable-cell');
        cell4.addClass('editable-cell');
        }
    else{
        cell.addClass('not-editable-cell');
        cell2.addClass('not-editable-cell');
        cell3.addClass('not-editable-cell');
        cell4.addClass('not-editable-cell');
    }
}
}
```

and then call onloadcomplete:

```
changeEditableByContain();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call this in you else condition, i didn't test it, but i think this should work

$("#mygrid").jqGrid('restoreRow',allIds[i]);

Comment: that's about a single cell attribute, not a row attribute

Comment: oh sorry you want to disable only cell editing...here you go buddy ...this answer will help you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092571/how-to-make-cell-editable-dynamically-in-jqgrid

Comment: the problem was I need to disable the entire row if one cell of the row contains somethin, this example is fine to single cell

Comment: so buddy the earlier solution $("#mygrid").jqGrid('restoreRow',allIds[i]); will restore the entire row...did you try something or you are just assuming things here?

Comment: post some code with the usage of retoreRow and lets figure out why its not restoring the entire row, cause the functionality of restoreRow is to restore the entire row

Comment: did u try this http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods...you can use this setColProp to dynamically add the properties to grid...try this thing