# Prevent editing of a specific editable row's cell in inline-edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In jqGrid, I'm working in inline-edit mode.

When the user try to edit a row(click on the pen action icon) I want to prevent(`{editable: false}`) the editing of a specific editable row's cell based on another cell's content in this row.

`grid.setColProp('myColumn',{editable:false});` is not good for me because this will disable the editing of 'myColumn' in all the grids's rows and I want to apply it **only on the currently edited row.**

Comment: Look at this old answer:

  [How to make cell editable dynamically in jqGrid][1]

Maybe it'll be helpful
    


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092571/how-to-make-cell-editable-dynamically-in-jqgrid

Comment: @Franky this answer is relevant for `cellEdit: true` mode only. I'm working in `inline-edit` mode as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value of the property `editable` is common for all rows, but the value will be used only by `editRow` method which *initialize* inline editing. So you can change the value of `editable` property dynamically with respect of `setColProp` (like in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7732536/315935)). It's important that you set the correct value of the `editable` property *before every call of `editRow`*. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308172/315935) you can see corresponding code example and the demo.

**UPDATED**: If you use `formatter: "actions"` then you can "subclass" the `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions` called in `onclick` handler. Below you can see an example of the corresponding code

```
var orgRowActions = $.fn.fmatter.rowactions;
$.fn.fmatter.rowactions = function (rid, gid, act, pos) {
    var $grid = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(gid)),
        rowData = $grid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rid),
        isNonEditable = false,
        result;
    // we can test any condition and change
    // editable property of any column
    if (act === "edit" && parseFloat(String(rowData.tax)) <= 20) {
        $grid.jqGrid("setColProp", "note", {editable: false});
        isNonEditable = true;
    }
    result = orgRowActions.call(this, rid, gid, act, pos);
    if (isNonEditable) {
        // reset the setting to original state
        $grid.jqGrid("setColProp", "note", {editable: true});
    }
    return result;
}
```

The corresponding demo you will find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubclassActions.htm). The "note" column is editable in the demo only if the value from the "tax" column is <= 20:

[image]

If you would have `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` without usage of `loadonce: true` you should replace call of `getLocalRow` to the call of `getRowData` or `getCell` in the above code.

Comment: the responsibly of calling the `editRow` command is not in my hands, I'm working with the `Actions` formatter (save, edit, delete, cancel). Any way to interfere before & after the `editRow` invocation with some events overriding?

Comment: @YairNevet: I added to my answer the "actions" specific implementation of the solution.

Comment: doing the job properly! Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: @Oleg   Since $.fn.fmatter.rowactions no longer uses four arguments and now just uses the action argument in newer versions of jqGrid. Is there a way to do this same specific row cell editing in newer versions of jqGrid?  I am working with version 4.5.2

Comment: @Snipe656: I am not sure which problem exactly you have in the implementation of "subclassing" in jqGrid 4.5.2. The replacement method `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions` should have the same number of parameters as the original. `result = orgRowActions.call(this, ...);` should use the parameters. To get information like `rowid` you can use `this`. See first lines of old implementation [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L256-L258).

Comment: @Oleg The issue I am running into is in 4.5.2 $.fn.fmatter.rowactions only has argument.  Line 5471 of jquery.jqGrid.src.js shows the function only is fed the "act" argument and in my tests that is just the action.  So I am having a hard time figuring out how to apply the solution from above when it seems like $.fn.fmatter.rowactions is not fed a row ID or any information specific to the grid.  It looks to me that your suggested rewrite of the function from below was applied to the core files:  https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/commit/e23c95e281b2eea52f4e1aa36d73b5f83cc91dec

Comment: @Oleg I guess another way I could word my comment is if I download the source from your example above that is found at http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubclassActions.htm and if i change the jqGrid version to 4.5.2 the solution no longer makes the Note column non editable. When I try to debug why that is, it appears to me it no longer works because the $.fn.fmatter.rowactions no longer is using multiple arguments but instead just the action value.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks, I figured out what I was doing wrong after re-reading your comments and re-evaluating my own code.  I am going to update my stackoverflow question on this so it contains the solution.

Comment: @Snipe656: OK! I'm glad to read that the problem is solved now. You are welcome!

Comment: please somebody tell me that where to insert this code - in in `$( document ).ready(function()` or in `onSelectRow : function(rowid, status, e)` and what are the values of the arguments {i.e. rid, gid, act, pos} of the function?

Comment: @Victor: Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: `version : "4.5.1"` I found this in jquery.jqGrid.js file. I guess this is the version of JQGrid.

Comment: @Victor: You can use right mouse click to open context menu and to choose "View page source" to see the source code of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubclassActions.htm). I posted you my answer where I recommend you to update to use free jqGrid 4.8 or better to download the latest sources from [github](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). In the case you will be able to solve the problem very easy.

Comment: Oleg, thanks for this.  Do you know if such methodology works with the tree grid as well?  I need to edit certain cells based on where they are in a tree grid - technically I think it has to be only leaves of the tree rows to be edited.  (That is the realistic and tentative, but not the final requirement)

Comment: @DimaR.: Yes, the same idea works with TreeGriid too, but the implementation efforts depends on the version of jqGrid which you use. Since the end of 2014 I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which is fork of jqGrid. See readmes for more information about the reasons, why I started my own fork. I implemented many new features described in [many wiki articles](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki). One can for example define `editable` as function (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) which simplify all