# jqGrid: Conditional editting of columns when editing row

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a table using jqGrid, I need that when editing a row some of the columns are not available for editing according to the values on the row. I know how to avoid the editing of a row according to the cell value but at the whole row level, I don’t know how to specify at the column level. Here is the function on double click of my table.

```
ondblClickRow: function(id){

    var code = id.split("-")[0];   
    var status = id.split("-")[1]; 
    if((code == "0" && status == "255") || (code == "1" && status == "0")
            || (code == "1" && status == "1")
            || (code == "2" && status == "255")){
        return;
    }else{
        jQuery('#nameableSignalsListView').jqGrid('editRow',id, { 
            keys : true,
            reloadAfterSubmit:true,
            successfunc: function(response, postdata) {                     
                var result = printErrors(response, false);
                if(result === true) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    customAlert(result);
                }, 200);    
                    return false;
                }
            },
            restoreAfterError: false,
            url: appRootUrl  + "rest/nameableSignals/update"
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered on the same question multiple times. The main understanding problem is that `editing: true` property of the column will be read by `editRow` at the initialization time. So you can set the value of `editing` property with respect of `setColProp` method for example **directly before calling of `editRow`**. In the way you can implement any dynamic behavior which you need.

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7732536/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308172/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956484/315935). The last one provide solution for the usage of inline editing per `formatter: "actions"`.