# How to disable inline editing in a cell based on data in a different cell on same row

Tags: jqgrid

I want to enable/disable inline editing on a cell based upon data found in a different cell.

I am using the formatter actions to display an Edit icon which seems to mean I can't do any checks via onSelectRow since that does not seem to get fired when the Edit icon is clicked.  After reading some various questions/solutions I thought I could simply disable/enable the editing for the entire column but that does not seem to be working in my code below and also I think that would be a bad route to take since looks like a user can click the edit icon on multiple rows within the same displayed icon and every row will display editable at the same time.  It seems like the best approach would be enable/disabling the editing at the cell level itself but I have tried that via the afterInsertRow and also the onEdit within the actions but neither seem to have any effect on if the cell can be edited or not.

This is using JQGrid 4.5.2, jQuery UI 1.9.1 and jQuery 1.8.2

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var noteIcon = '<div title="Job Details" style="float:left; margin-left:5px;" class="ui-pg-div ui-inline-edit" onmouseover="jQuery(this).addClass(\'ui-state-hover\');" onmouseout="jQuery(this).removeClass(\'ui-state-hover\');"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-note"></span></div>';

            getColumnIndexByName = function(grid,columnName) {
                var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
                for (var i=0,l=cm.length; i<l; i++) {
                    if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
                        return i; // return the index
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            };

            jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, { 
                altRows:true,
                altclass:'myAltRowClass',
                datatype: "json", 
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "ROWS", 
                    page: "PAGE", 
                    total: "TOTAL", 
                    records: "RECORDS", 
                    cell: "", 
                    id: "0"
                }, 
                emptyrecords: "No jobs to display.",
                rowList: [25,50,100], 
                viewrecords: true, 
                height: "auto", 
                loadonce: true, 
                footerrow: true, 
                loadComplete: function (data) {
                    var $self = $(this), i = getColumnIndexByName($self, 'action');

                    $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child("+(i+1)+") > div:nth-child(1)",$self[0]).click(function(e) {
                        var tr=$(e.target,$self[0].rows).closest("tr.jqgrow");

                        e.preventDefault();
                        window.location.href = 'CenterView.cfm?table=ORDER_JOBS&ID=' + tr[0].id + '&backurl=%3DJobsInbox%2Ecfm%3FPICK%5FDMS%5FCENTERID%3D15';
                    });

                }, 
                colNames: [ "ID", "Delivery Type", "Service Type", "Pre-Commit", "Survey Name", "Client", "Order ID", "Job Number", "Client Reference","Internal Reference", "Type", "Product Name", "Submitted For", "Sales Coordinator", "Order Date", "Requested Date", "Standard Date", "Inbox Date", "Delivery Hold", "Pre-Commit Hold", "Analyst", "&nbsp;", "Actions" ], 
                colModel: [ 
                    { name: "id", index: "id", hidden: true, key: true }, 
                    { name: "delivery_type", index: "delivery_type", width: 70, formatter:'select', stype:'select', edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":All;External Delivery:External Delivery;Internal Data Access:Internal Data Access;Internal Delivery:Internal Delivery" } }, 
                    { name: "service_type", index: "service_type", width: 65, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']} }, 
                    { name: "isprecommit", index: "isprecommit", width: 50, align: "center", formatter:'select', stype:'select', edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":All;false:No;true:Yes" } }, 
                    { name: "survey_name", index: "survey_name", searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']}, formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'LinkStation.cfm', addParam: '&Type=JobsInboxSurvey&PICK_DMS_CENTERID=15'} }, 
                    { name: "corpname", index: "corpname", searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']}, formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'LinkStation.cfm', addParam: '&Type=JobsInboxClient&PICK_DMS_CENTERID=15'} }, 
                    { name: "orderid", index: "orderid", width: 40, formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'LinkStation.cfm', addParam: '&Type=JobsInboxOrder&PICK_DMS_CENTERID=15'}, search:false }, 
                    { name: "jobsnumber", index: "jobsnumber", width: 60, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']}, formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'CenterView.cfm', addParam: '&table=ORDER_JOBS&backurl=%3DJobsInbox%2Ecfm%3FPICK%5FDMS%5FCENTERID%3D15'} }, 
                    { name: "clientref", index: "clientref", width: 60, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']} }, 
                    { name: "internal_reference", index: "internal_reference", width: 33, formatter:'select', stype:'select', edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":;EOM:EOM;NO GO:NO GO" } }, 
                    { name: "survey_type", index: "survey_type", width: 35, align: "center", formatter:'select', stype:'select', edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":All;2D:2D;3D:3D" } }, 
                    { name: "product_name", index: "product_name", searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']} }, 
                    { name: "submitted_for", index: "submitted_for", width: 70, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']} }, 
                    { name: "sales_coordinator", index: "sales_coordinator", width: 70, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']} }, 
                    { name: "order_date", index: "order_date", width: 50, align: "center", search:false, datefmt: 'mm/dd/yy' }, 
                    { name: "requested_date", index: "requested_date", width: 50, align: "center", search:false, datefmt: 'mm/dd/yy' }, 
                    { name: "dt_standard", index: "dt_standard", width: 50, align: "center", search:false, datefmt: 'mm/dd/yy' }, 
                    { name: "inbox_date", index: "inbox_date", width: 50, align: "center", search:false, datefmt: 'mm/dd/yy' }, 
                    { name: "isdeliveryhold", index: "isdeliveryhold", sortable: true, search: true, width: 50, align: "center", formatter:'select', stype:'select', editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":;false:No;true:Yes" } }, 
                    { name: "isprecommithold", index: "isprecommithold", sortable: true, search: true, width: 50, align: "center", formatter:'select', stype:'select', editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":;false:No;true:Yes" } }, 
                    { name: "analyst", index: "analyst", width: 115, align: "center", sortable: true, search: true, formatter:'select', stype:'select', editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":;michael-19810202:Mike Hares;sara-20061004:Sara Kathleen Lampman" } }, 
                    { name: 'action', index: 'action', sortable: false, search: false, width: 25, formatter: function() { return noteIcon; } }, 
                    { name: "act", index: "act", width: 55, align: "center", sortable: false, search:false, formatter: "actions", 
                            formatoptions: {
                                keys: true, delbutton: false, afterSave: function() { $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype:'json'}); $(this).trigger('reloadGrid', [{page:1}]); }, 
                                onEdit:function(rowid) {
                                    var localRowData = $(this).jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid);

                                    if(localRowData.isprecommit == true) {
                                        // $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'isprecommithold', {editable:true});
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        // $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'isprecommithold', {editable:false});
                                        $(this).setCell(rowid,"isprecommithold","",'not-editable-cell');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                ], 
                editurl: "Components/JobsInbox.cfc?method=SetJobUpdate&UPDATEDBY=aaron-20040630", 
                afterInsertRow: 
                    function(rowid, aData){ 
                        /*
                        if(aData.isprecommit == false) {
                            $(this).setCell(rowid,"isprecommithold","",'not-editable-cell');
                        }
                        */
                        if(aData.isdeliveryhold) {
                            $(this).setCell(rowid,"isdeliveryhold","",{"background":"#FF6A6A"});
                        }
                    }
            }); 

            $('#Jobs').jqGrid({
                url: "Components/JobsInbox.cfc?method=GetJobGrid&PICK_DMS_CENTERID=15&CFDateFormat=MM/DD/YY", 
                caption: "Jobs Inbox", 
                pager: $('#JobsPager')              
            });
            $('#Jobs').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOperators: false, ignoreCase: true });
            $('#Jobs').jqGrid('navGrid', '#JobsPager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, refresh: false });
            $('#Jobs').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#JobsPager', { caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-refresh", title: $.jgrid.nav.refreshtitle, onClickButton: function() { $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype:'json'}); $(this).trigger('reloadGrid', [{page:1}]); } });

        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .myAltRowClass { background-color: #ECF6FC; background-image: none; }

        /* Wrap in header cell */
        .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {
            height:auto;
            overflow:hidden;
            padding-right:4px;
            padding-top:2px;
            position:relative;
            vertical-align:text-top;
            white-space:normal !important;
        }

        /* Wrap in table cell */
        .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
            white-space: normal !important;
            height:auto;
            vertical-align:text-top;
            padding-top:2px;
        }

        span.cellWithoutBackground {
            display:block;
            background-image:none;
            margin-right:-2px;
            margin-left:-2px;
            height:14px;
            padding:4px;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the basic answer to this via this other question at [Prevent editing of a specific editable row's cell in inline-edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955568/prevent-editing-of-a-specific-editable-rows-cell-in-inline-edit-mode)

Here is the working code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var noteIcon = '<div title="Job Details" style="float:left; margin-left:5px;" class="ui-pg-div ui-inline-edit" onmouseover="jQuery(this).addClass(\'ui-state-hover\');" onmouseout="jQuery(this).removeClass(\'ui-state-hover\');"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-note"></span></div>';

        getColumnIndexByName = function(grid,columnName) {
            var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
            for (var i=0,l=cm.length; i<l; i++) {
                if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
                    return i; // return the index
                }
            }
            return -1;
        };

        DoDeliveryHolds = function(grid) {
            var aryIDS  = $(grid).jqGrid('getDataIDs');

            if(aryIDS.length > 0) {
                // Add Ajax call to do toggle in database
                alert(aryIDS.length);
            }
        };

        // Here we set the altRows option globallly
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, { 
            altRows:true,
            altclass:'myAltRowClass',
            datatype: "json", 
            jsonReader: {
                root: "ROWS", 
                page: "PAGE", 
                total: "TOTAL", 
                records: "RECORDS", 
                cell: "", 
                id: "0"
            }, 
            emptyrecords: "No jobs to display.",
            rowList: [25,50,100], 
            viewrecords: true, 
            height: "auto", 
            loadonce: true, 
            footerrow: true, 
            loadComplete: function (data) {
                var $self = $(this), i = getColumnIndexByName($self, 'action');

                // nth-child need 1-based index so we use (i+1) below
                $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child("+(i+1)+") > div:nth-child(1)",$self[0]).click(function(e) {
                    var tr=$(e.target,$self[0].rows).closest("tr.jqgrow");

                    e.preventDefault();
                    window.location.href = 'CenterView.cfm?table=ORDER_JOBS&ID=' + tr[0].id + '&backurl=%3DJobsInbox%2Ecfm%3FPICK%5FDMS%5FCENTERID%3D15';
                });

            }, 
            colNames: [ "ID", "Delivery Type", "Service Type", "Pre-Commit", "Survey Name", "Client", "Order ID", "Job Number", "Client Reference","Internal Reference", "Type", "Product Name", "Submitted For", "Sales Coordinator", "Order Date", "Requested Date", "Standard Date", "Inbox Date", "Delivery Hold", "Pre-Commit Hold", "Analyst", "&nbsp;", "Actions" ], 
            colModel: [ 
                { name: "id", index: "id", hidden: true, key: true }, 
                { name: "delivery_type", index: "delivery_type", width: 70, formatter:'select', stype:'select', edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":All;External Delivery:External Delivery;Internal Data Access:Internal Data Access;Internal Delivery:Internal Delivery" } }, 
                { name: "service_type", index: "service_type", width: 65, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']} }, 
                { name: "isprecommit", index: "isprecommit", width: 50, align: "center", formatter:'select', stype:'select', edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":All;false:No;true:Yes" } }, 
                { name: "survey_name", index: "survey_name", searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']}, formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'LinkStation.cfm', addParam: '&Type=JobsInboxSurvey&PICK_DMS_CENTERID=15'} }, 
                { name: "corpname", index: "corpname", searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']}, formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'LinkStation.cfm', addParam: '&Type=JobsInboxClient&PICK_DMS_CENTERID=15'} }, 
                { name: "orderid", index: "orderid", width: 40, formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'LinkStation.cfm', addParam: '&Type=JobsInboxOrder&PICK_DMS_CENTERID=15'}, search:false }, 
                { name: "jobsnumber", index: "jobsnumber", width: 60, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']}, formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'CenterView.cfm', addParam: '&table=ORDER_JOBS&backurl=%3DJobsInbox%2Ecfm%3FPICK%5FDMS%5FCENTERID%3D15'} }, 
                { name: "clientref", index: "clientref", width: 60, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']} }, 
                { name: "internal_reference", index: "internal_reference", width: 33, formatter:'select', stype:'select', edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":;EOM:EOM;NO GO:NO GO" } }, 
                { name: "survey_type", index: "survey_type", width: 35, align: "center", formatter:'select', stype:'select', edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":All;2D:2D;3D:3D" } }, 
                { name: "product_name", index: "product_name", searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']} }, 
                { name: "submitted_for", index: "submitted_for", width: 70, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']} }, 
                { name: "sales_coordinator", index: "sales_coordinator", width: 70, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','bn','nc','ew','en']} }, 
                { name: "order_date", index: "order_date", width: 50, align: "center", search:false, datefmt: 'mm/dd/yy' }, 
                { name: "requested_date", index: "requested_date", width: 50, align: "center", search:false, datefmt: 'mm/dd/yy' }, 
                { name: "dt_standard", index: "dt_standard", width: 50, align: "center", search:false, datefmt: 'mm/dd/yy' }, 
                { name: "inbox_date", index: "inbox_date", width: 50, align: "center", search:false, datefmt: 'mm/dd/yy' }, 
                { name: "isdeliveryhold", index: "isdeliveryhold", sortable: true, search: true, width: 50, align: "center", formatter:'select', stype:'select', editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":;false:No;true:Yes" } }, 
                { name: "isprecommithold", index: "isprecommithold", sortable: true, search: true, width: 50, align: "center", formatter:'select', stype:'select', editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":;false:No;true:Yes" } }, 
                { name: "analyst", index: "analyst", width: 115, align: "center", sortable: true, search: true, formatter:'select', stype:'select', editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: ":;michael-19810202:Mike Hares;sara-20061004:Sara Kathleen Lampman" } }, 
                { name: 'action', index: 'action', sortable: false, search: false, width: 25, formatter: function() { return noteIcon; } }, 
                { name: "act", index: "act", width: 55, align: "center", sortable: false, search:false, formatter: "actions", 
                        formatoptions: {
                            keys: true, delbutton: false, afterSave: function() { $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype:'json'}); $(this).trigger('reloadGrid', [{page:1}]); }
                        }
                }
            ], 
            editurl: "Components/JobsInbox.cfc?method=SetJobUpdate&UPDATEDBY=aaron-20040630", 
            afterInsertRow: 
                function(rowid, aData){ 
                    if(aData.isdeliveryhold) {
                        $(this).setCell(rowid,"isdeliveryhold","",{"background":"#FF6A6A"});
                    }
                }
        }); 

        $('#Jobs').jqGrid({
            url: "Components/JobsInbox.cfc?method=GetJobGrid&PICK_DMS_CENTERID=15&CFDateFormat=MM/DD/YY", 
            caption: "Jobs Inbox", 
            pager: $('#JobsPager')              
        });
        $('#Jobs').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOperators: false, ignoreCase: true });
        $('#Jobs').jqGrid('navGrid', '#JobsPager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, refresh: false });
        $('#Jobs').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#JobsPager', { caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-refresh", title: $.jgrid.nav.refreshtitle, onClickButton: function() { $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype:'json'}); $(this).trigger('reloadGrid', [{page:1}]); } });
        $('#Jobs').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#JobsPager', { caption: "Toggle Delivery Holds", buttonicon: "ui-icon-pencil", onClickButton: function() { var str = confirm("Toggle the Delivery Hold for all displayed Jobs?"); if(str) { DoDeliveryHolds($(this)); } } });

        var orgRowActions = $.fn.fmatter.rowactions;
        $.fn.fmatter.rowactions = function (act) {
            var $tr = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow"),
                rid = $tr.attr("id"),
                $grid = $(this).closest("table.ui-jqgrid-btable"),
                rowData = $grid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rid),
                isNonEditable = false,
                result; 

            // editable property of any column
            if (act === "edit" && rowData.isprecommit == false) {
                $grid.jqGrid("setColProp", "isprecommithold", {editable: false});
                isNonEditable = true;
            }
            result = orgRowActions.call(this, act);
            if (isNonEditable) {
                // reset the setting to original state
                $grid.jqGrid("setColProp", "isprecommithold", {editable: true});
            }
            return result;
        }

    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .myAltRowClass { background-color: #ECF6FC; background-image: none; }

    /* Wrap in header cell */
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {
        height:auto;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding-right:4px;
        padding-top:2px;
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:text-top;
        white-space:normal !important;
    }

    /* Wrap in table cell */
    .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
        white-space: normal !important;
        height:auto;
        vertical-align:text-top;
        padding-top:2px;
    }

    span.cellWithoutBackground {
        display:block;
        background-image:none;
        margin-right:-2px;
        margin-left:-2px;
        height:14px;
        padding:4px;
    }
</style>
```