# Making actions appears in JQGrid only when a boolean is true

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have data displayed in a JQGrid, and I get an Actions column, where I have icons for Delete and Edit actions. In the data I retrieve to display in the grid, I have a boolean, and I would like to display the icons only when the boolean is true. How could it be done?

Here the piece of code of my JQGrid display:

```
jQuery("#datagrid").jqGrid({
        stateOptions: getStateOptions("creation-site"),
        url: listUrl,
        datatype: "json",
        loadError: viewError,
        colNames: ['', 'Nom', 'N de dépôt Geopost', 'IATA', 'Groupe ID', 'Site de rattachement', 'Poste comptable', 'Centre cout', 'Description'],
        colModel: [
            {name: 'myac', width: 80, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false, formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: {keys: true, editbutton: true, }},
            {name: 'nom', index: 'nom', editable: true, edittype: "text", sortable: true},
            {name: 'geopostDepotNumber', index: 'geopostDepotNumber', editable: true, edittype: "text", sortable: true},
            {name: 'iata', index: 'iata', editable: true, edittype: "text", sortable: true},
            {name: 'groupeId', index: 'groupeId', editable: true, edittype: "text", sortable: true},
            {name: 'siteRattachement', index: 'siteRattachement', editable: true, edittype: "text", sortable: true},
            {name: 'posteComptable', index: 'posteComptable', editable: true, edittype: "text", sortable: true},
            {name: 'centreCout', index: 'centreCout', editable: true, edittype: "text", sortable: true},
            {name: 'description', index: 'description', editable: true, edittype: "text", sortable: true}
        ],
        rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000],
        pager: '#navGrid',
        sortname: 'title',
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        height: 'auto',
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        caption: '<spring:message code="creationsite.title"/>'
    });
```

Edit: Here a sample JSON, for 2 lines:

```
[{"id":1,"centreCout":"211177","geopostDepotNumber":"0401","iata":"MLV","posteComptable":"77999","referentielId":5,"siteRattachement":" ","nom":"Ceci est un nom","networkRefId":1,"networkRefName":"FR-CHR","description":"MARNE-LA-VALLEE","groupeId":"CHRF","manual":false},
{"id":2,"centreCout":"211174","geopostDepotNumber":"0402","iata":"FTV","posteComptable":"75998","referentielId":5,"siteRattachement":" ","nom":null,"networkRefId":1,"networkRefName":"FR-CHR","description":"ALFORTVILLE","groupeId":"CHRF","manual":false}]
```

The actions should be disabled depending on the "manual" field in the JSON.

Edit: Following what I understood from Oleg's answer, I added that to my grid:

```
rowattr: function (rd) {
            if (rd.manual === false) { // verify that the testing is correct in your case
                return {"class": "not-editable-row"};
            }
        },
```

but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then it would be enough to hide the column `myac` conditionally directly after the grid is created or after you set the value `isReadOnly`:

```
if (isReadOnly) {
    jQuery("#datagrid").jqGrid("hideCol", "myac");
}
```

Another common remark. I'd recommend you to examine the value from `Default` column on [the page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) of the documentation. You will see that default value of `edittype` and `sortable` are "text" and `true` values which you use for all columns of `colModel`. Additionally you can consider to change default value of `colModel` items with respect of `cmTemplate` (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)). One more remark: the values of `index` have to be the same as the value of `name` in case of usage `loadonce: true`. If one don't specify `index` then the value of `name` property will be used instead automatically. So you can reduce `colModel` from your code example to

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'myac', width: 80, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false,
        formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: { keys: true, editbutton: true },
        editable: false },
    { name: 'nom' },
    { name: 'geopostDepotNumber' },
    { name: 'iata' },
    { name: 'groupeId' },
    { name: 'siteRattachement' },
    { name: 'posteComptable' },
    { name: 'centreCout' },
    { name: 'description' }
],
cmTemplate: { editable: true }
```

Such code can be much more easy be read and to be maintained.

By the way if you know the value of `isReadOnly` *before* the grid is created you can use additionally

```
cmTemplate: { editable: !isReadOnly }
```

The last remark: you use `sortorder: "asc"` option which has default value. You can remove the option. You should verify whether `sortname: 'title'` is correct, because you don't have the column `'title'`. I suppose that it's just a "cut and pasted" error.

**UPDATED**: If you need to disable editing of some rows you can do the following

```
rowattr: function (rowData) {
    if (rowData.manual === false) {
        return { "class": "not-editable-row" };
    }
},
loadComplete: function () {
    $(this).find("tr.not-editable-row")
        .find(".ui-inline-edit,.ui-inline-del")
        .hide();
}
```

[The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/non-editable-row-formatter-actions.htm) uses the value from the `Closed` column to disable editing. The resulting grid looks like on the picture below

[image]

Comment: Actually, no, that's not what I want to do. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I want my icons to appear on some rows (when the boolean defined for each row is true) and not on others (when the boolean is false).

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy: Sorry, but I still don't understand what you want. You wrote in the text of your question: "I would like to display the icons only when the boolean is true." What you want really? If you execute `jQuery("#datagrid").jqGrid("hideCol", "myac");` then the column which holds the Edit and Delete buttons disappears. Is it not exactly what you just wrote in your comment? I wrote you that it's very important to know **when** you set the value of "the boolean"? Is it known *before* the grid is created? Is it a part of server response with jqGrid data? ...

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy: If you need to make only some *specific* rows editable you can use `rowattr` to add `"not-editable-row"` class to the rows. So editing of the rows will be not possible. Look [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) where you need just replace `"myAltRowClass"` to `"not-editable-row"`. One more option are described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12956484/315935).

Comment: Yes, I get my boolean from my Tomcat server. I will attach a sample JSON to my question. And yes, I want to make some lines non-editable/deletable

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy: And what boolean you mean from the JSON data? Is it `manual` filed associated with the row? Means the field of input data that the row is editable?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would like.

Comment: Ok, `rd` contains the data for each row of the grid. So if I add a hidden column containing the "manual" boolean, it's working: nothing happens when I click on the edit button of a line with manual=false. But I can't distinguish between editable lines and not editable ones. I should probably add another style. Do you know anything that could come handy?

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy: See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: By the way, why do I get the inline button? I would like form editing, actually...

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy: If you want to use form editing instead of inline editing you should add `editformbutton: true` option to `formatoptions`. If you will need to specify and other options of form editing you should use `editOptions` property of `formatoptions`. For example `formatoptions: { editformbutton: true, editOptions: { closeAfterEdit: true }}`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but when I click on the + button at the bottom, to add a row, the icons appear again. Do you know why? I'm using a form edit.

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy: Sorry, but you should describe the problem more detailed. Which "+" button you use? Do you use Add of `inlineNav` or `navGrid`? Which icons appear again? In new added row or in all rows? Which options of inline editing of form editing you use?