# customize jqGrid edit button inside row to open new view

Tags: jqgrid

So the default behavior for the edit button inside each row of jqGrid is to open the form in the same page, right?

I need it to open another view, another URL.

I've managed to do this with the edit button that is located in the grid-pager, using the .navButtonAdd method. But I can't figure out how to do the same for the row buttons.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid don't provide currently any simple way to replace the call of editing to another method or to include custom button. What you can do alternatively is "subclassing" `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions` function like I describe it in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956484/315935). The `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions` function will be called on click on any from action buttons. So you can test whether the `act` parameter is `"edit"` or not. In case of non `"edit"` button you can forward the call to original `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions` function. In case of `"edit"` button you can do any your custom action instead.

**UPDATED**: The exact implementation depends a little from the version of jqGrid which you use because parameters and the value of `this` of the function `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions` are different for different versions of jqGrid. I created for you [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons2-fa4-subclassing.htm) which uses [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (see [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)). I used the following code for subclassing

```js
var orgRowActions = $.fn.fmatter.rowactions;
$.fn.fmatter.rowactions = function (e, act) {
    var $grid = $(this).closest("table.ui-jqgrid-btable"),
        rowid = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");

    if (act === "edit") {
        $grid.jqGrid("viewGridRow", rowid);
        return false;
    }
    return orgRowActions.call(this, e, act);
}
```

As the result the "Edit" button starts "View" instead of edit form.

I plan to include more customization possibilities in the next version of free jqGrid. So one will be able to create custom inline icon without the tricks with subclassing.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, Oleg.

I think I'm doing something wrong, though. Sorry, this is kinda obscure to me :/ 

Based on the link you posted, I'm doing this: 

`var orgRowActions = $.fn.fmatter.rowactions;
$.fn.fmatter.rowactions = function (rid, gid, act, pos) {
    var $grid = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(gid)),
        rowData = $grid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rid),
        isNonEditable = false,
        result;

    if (act === "edit") {
        window.location = myURL;
    }
    
    result = orgRowActions.call(this, rid, gid, act, pos);

    return result;
}`

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @LucasGabriel: I created the demo for you which demonstrates the implementation. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: thank you so much! that was it. I'm using version 4.6.0 and the parameters are different, indeed.

it's working just fine now!

Comment: @LucasGabriel: You are welcome! I think that the interface of `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions` is the same in 4.6.0 and in free jqGrid 4.8, so you can use the same code in 4.6 too. I still recommend you to try free jqGrid which is free of cause like jqGrid 4.6 and it contains many new features and bug fixes. It's the fork of jqGrid which I will continue to develop in the future.

Comment: I'll be using that, then. my project is in early stage so I'd better change it right away.