# How to make editable:false for jqgrid cell in INLINE edit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955568/prevent-editing-of-a-specific-editable-rows-cell-in-inline-edit-mode) to make cell non editable as per condition but don't know where to place this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955568/prevent-editing-of-a-specific-editable-rows-cell-in-inline-edit-mode?answertab=active#tab-top), in `$( document ).ready(function()` or `in onSelectRow : function(rowid, status, e)` and what are the meanings of the parameters passed to that function? I'm newbie in Jquery. Let me know if you want to see my code for the same. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use free jqGrid then the solution would be very easy. One can specify function as the value of `editable` property. So you can specify callback function which inform jqGrid which cells of the columns will be editable and which not. See [the article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) for details.

Comment: @Victor: You are welcome! I implemented the feature "`editable` property as function" specially for such cases. I include permanently new features in my fork of jqGrid (in free jqGrid) based on the problems which I find during answering of answers on the stackoverflow. I recommend you to look through [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) to see what is already implemented and to decide whether you should upgrade to free jqGrid or not.

Comment: @Victor: The callback `editable` (like the most other new callback) have **one parameter** with many properties. It's the common rule which I try to follows. It reduces the number of unused parameters (if you need only the 4-th parameter) and to allow easy to extend the functionality in the future without breaking compatibility of the code which uses previous version.