# How to make only the clicked cell editable instead of all the editable cells in the row clicked - using jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

At present I'm getting all the cells (with editable:true) in the row editable in which i clicked and not only the clicked the cell. The table is similar to the table in this link: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing4.htm. I've gone through the link: [http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing), but didn't help (may be due to my fault in the way i tried) and also tried the answers given in stackoverflow related questions (used the attributes: cellEdit: true, cellsubmit: "clientArray").

Please help me using the above link as reference http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing4.htm (I think mainly the  "onSelectRow", "ondblClickRow" functions need to be updated. i tried onSelectCell etc. but failed! ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without posting the code it will be difficult to help. Looks like you want cell edit not the row edit

Comment: You can use the link: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing4.htm for reference. my code is similar to it.

Comment: Apart from that reference link my data gets saved after inline edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use cell editing you have to include `cellEdit: true` in jqGrid definition. If you use local datatype then you should use [cellsubmit: "clientArray"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#properties) additionally. If you want to save data on the remote source you have to implement editing in your server code and specify `cellurl` option of jqGrid. [The documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server) describes what jqGrid send to the server on saving of cell.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've already tried those attributes (forgot to mention in question - now updated). I think i need to change "onSelectRow", "ondblClickRow" functions. Can you please tell me how to update those functions to make the clicked cell editable?

Comment: @SankarV: You are welcome! If you just include `cellEdit: true, cellsubmit: "clientArray"` options to jqGrid and include `editable: true` property to columns which you want to allow to edit all should work. If you want edit all columns of the grid you can use `cmTemplate: {editable: true}` option of jqGrid. It changes defualt value of `editable` property in colModel from `false` to `true` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)).

Comment: `{name:'qty',index:'qty', sorttype:"float", editable:true,editrules:{required:true,integer:true}, cellEdit: true,cellsubmit: "clientArray"},`



- this is the field definition.
when i click on it (qty) all the columns with  `editable:true` becomes editable!

Comment: @SankarV: `cellEdit: true, cellsubmit: "clientArray"` are [jqGrid options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) and not properties of [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) option. You should move `cellEdit: true, cellsubmit: "clientArray"` to the correct place.

Comment: @SankarV: See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NonEditableCellsDynamic.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5092645/315935) as an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg :) ! `cellEdit: true, cellsubmit: "clientArray` were in wrong place. Also your demo is something I was looking for since the last 6 hours. By the way I started learning jqgrid yesterday :) ! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on an Angular 2 app with Typescript, and I had a different need where I wanted to be able to click a row in the grid, but only have one cell editable.  I didn't like the user experience where the user had to click the actual cell to edit it.  Instead, clicking the row highlights the row and then makes the one cell editable.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The trick was that I needed to set cellEdit to false on the grid and then set the individual column editable to true when declaring my column model array, and write a change event for the editoptions of the column.  I also had to write code for the the onSelectRow event of the grid, to keep track of the current row selected and to restore the previous row selected.  A snippet of the Typescript code is below:

```
  private generateGrid() {

let colNames = ['id', 'Name', 'Total', 'Assigned', 'Distributed', 'Remaining', 'Total', 'Assigned', 'Remaining', 'Expiration'];
let self = this;

// declare variable to hold Id of last row selected in the grid
let lastRowId;

let colModel = [
  { name: 'id', key: true, hidden: true },
  { name: 'name' },

  { name: 'purchasedTotalCount', width: 35, align: 'center' },
  { name: 'purchasedAssignedCount', width: 35, align: 'center' },
  { name: 'purchasedDistributedCount', width: 35, align: 'center' },
  { name: 'purchasedRemainingCount', width: 35, align: 'center' },
  // receivedTotalCount is the only editable cell;
  // the custom change event works in conjunction with the onSelectRow event
  // to get row editing to work, but only for this one cell as being editable;
  // also note that cellEdit is set to false on the entire grid, otherwise it would
  // require that the individual cell is selected in order to edit it, and not just
  // anywhere on the row, which is the better user experience
  { name: 'receivedTotalCount',
    width: 35,
    align: 'center',
    editable: true,
    edittype: 'text',
    editoptions: {
      dataEvents: [
        {
          type: 'change', fn: function(e) {
            //TODO: don't allow decimal numbers, or just round down
            let count = parseInt(this.value);
            if (isNaN(count) || count < 0 || count > 1000) {
              alert('Value must be a whole number between 0 and 1000.');
            } else {
              self.updateLicenses(parseInt(lastRowId), count);
            }
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  { name: 'receivedAssignedCount', width: 35, align: 'center' },
  { name: 'receivedRemainingCount', width: 35, align: 'center' },
  { name: 'expirationDate', width: 45, align: 'center', formatter: 'date' }
];

jQuery('#licenseManagerGrid').jqGrid({
  data: this.childTenants,
  datatype: 'local',
  colNames: colNames,
  colModel: colModel,
  altRows: true,
  rowNum: 25,
  rowList: [25, 50, 100],
  width: 1200,
  height: '100%',
  viewrecords: true,
  emptyrecords: '',
  ignoreCase: true,
  cellEdit: false,  // must be false in order for row select with cell edit to work properly
  cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
  cellurl: 'clientArray',
  editurl: 'clientArray',
  pager: '#licenseManagerGridPager',
  jsonReader: {
    id: 'id',
      repeatitems: false
  },

  // make the selected row editable and restore the previously-selected row back to what it was
  onSelectRow: function(rowid, status) {
    if (lastRowId === undefined) {
      lastRowId = rowid;
    }
    else {
      jQuery('#licenseManagerGrid').restoreRow(lastRowId);
      lastRowId = rowid;
    }
    jQuery('#licenseManagerGrid').editRow(rowid, false);
  },
});
}
```

Additionally, I wanted the escape key to allow the user to abort changes to the cell and then restore the cell to its previous state.  This was accomplished with the following Angular 2 code in Typescript:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'license-manager',
  template: template,
  styles: [style],
  host: {
    '(document:keydown)': 'handleKeyboardEvents($event)'
  }
})

// handle keypress so a row can be restored if user presses Escape
private handleKeyboardEvents(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    let selRow = jQuery('#licenseManagerGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    if (selRow) {
      jQuery('#licenseManagerGrid').restoreRow(selRow);
    }
  }
}
```